# def inside def gives an error when used with ref

Tags: tex-core, expansion, def

I want to define a command that returns a label to use with `\ref`, but it requires using \edef to expand another command. However, I am getting several errors starting with `Missing \endcsname inserted.` for the following M(not)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:test-10}
  A=B
\end{equation}

\def\test#1{%
  \edef\arg{test}%
  \arg-#1}

This works \test{10}. But this doesn't \ref{eq:\test{10}}.
\end{document}
```

I also tried
`\ref\expandafter{eq:\test{10}}`
but then I get the error
`File ended while scanning use of \@setref.`

I am clearly misunderstanding something fundamental about expansion, can someone explain? Is there a way to fix it?

EDIT: As asked by responders, here's my (not so minimal) use-case. The command to get the label is a bit complicated

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\mytest#1{\@mytest#1--\relax}
\def\@stripdashes#1-#2\relax{#1}

\def\@mytest#1-#2-#3\relax{%
  \edef\@arg@third{\@stripdashes#3-\relax}%
  \ifx\@arg@third\empty%
    % No year
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%
      % No month
      ONE-TWO-#1%
    \else%
      ONE-#1-#2%
    \fi%
  \else#1-#2-\@arg@third\fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:ONE-TWO-3}
  A=B
\end{equation}

This works: \mytest{3}, \mytest{TWO-3}

But not this:
\ref{\mytest{3}}, \ref{\mytest{TWO-3}}

\end{document}
```

In reality, ONE and TWO are other commands that dynamically construct the label.

Comment: the argument of `\ref` has to expand to a label name, so can not have assignment sor other non-expandable constructs. To fix it, just remove the assignment.

Comment: looking at your edit you don't need edef at all, just test for empty using if rather than ifx or simpler use expl3 code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When LaTeX processes `\ref{foo}` it basically looks whether the control sequence `\r@foo` is defined (with `@` a letter) and in order to do this it performs

```
\csname r@foo\endcsname
```

The tokens inside `\csname...\endcsname` must expand to character tokens. In your case LaTeX tries

```
\csname r@eq:\test{10}\endcsname
```

and `\test` is expanded leading to

```
\csname r@eq:\edef\arg{10}\endcsname
```

which is illegal. You ***can't*** perform macro definitions inside `\csname...\endcsname` and, indeed, you get `Missing \endcsname` as soon as `\edef` is scanned. TeX now tries to recover by inserting `\endcsname` in front of the offending token, but obviously this results in other errors that are actually meaningless.

For your use case (explained after I gave the answer above), define `\@test` with *four* arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\mytest#1{eq:\@mytest#1---\@nil}

\def\@mytest#1-#2-#3-#4\@nil{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
    % No year
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      % No month
      ONE-TWO-#1%
    \else
      ONE-#1-#2%
    \fi
  \else
    #1-#2-#3%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:ONE-TWO-3}
  A=B
\end{equation}

This works: \mytest{3}, \mytest{TWO-3}, \mytest{ONE-TWO-3}

But not this:
\ref{\mytest{3}}, \ref{\mytest{TWO-3}}, \ref{\mytest{ONE-TWO-3}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I added my usecase as an edit. I use the edef to expand a command for subsequent testing with \ifx inside my command. I am not sure there's an easy way to get around using \edef.

Comment: @Tohiko See edit.

Answer (score 2):

The argument needs to expand to a label name, so remove the assignment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:test-10}
  A=B
\end{equation}

\def\test#1{%
  test-#1}

This works \test{10}. But this doesn't \ref{eq:\test{10}}.
\end{document}
```

The above works as intended.

---

There is nothing really special about `\ref` here; you would see the same kind of failure in for example

```
\setcounter{section}{\def\tmp{2}\tmp}
```

or

```
\setcounter{\def\tmp{section}\tmp}{2}
```

The arguments of `\setcounter` need to exand to a counter name and a `<number>` but an assignment to `\tmp` followed by expanding `\tmp` may *print* as a section name or a number (or a label name) but it does not work by expansion.

---

The extended version added to the question later is similar, you just need to use an expandable test for `#3` just as you do already for `#1` (more complicated cases could use `\expanded` (or expl3 `e` arguments) instead of `\edef` (expl3 `x` arguments) but here it's not needed at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\mytest#1{\@mytest#1---\relax}

\def\@mytest#1-#2-#3-#4\relax{%
  eq:% missing from example in question here or in the `\ref`
  \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
    % No year
    \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
      % No month
      ONE-TWO-#1%
    \else%
      ONE-#1-#2%
    \fi%
  \else#1-#2-#3%
\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:ONE-TWO-3}
  A=B
\end{equation}

This works: \mytest{3}, \mytest{TWO-3}

But not this:
\ref{\mytest{3}}, \ref{\mytest{TWO-3}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The assignment was just a MWE to illustrate the point. I understand the issue now, but not sure how to fix it in my usecase where I need edef to expand some command for subsequent \ifx comparision.

Comment: @Tohiko you can probably use `\expanded` or `\expandafter` which is why in expl3 code `e` and `f` arguments are allowed in expandable functions but `x` arguments which use exec are not

Comment: @Tohiko I added an example